# Python Pandas: Empty row included when writing to excel file. How to prevent this?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

so my code writes just fine to the excel sheet but it adds an unnecessary row into the excel sheet right below the established columns. Here's the output:

[image]

Row 3 has an empty row that shouldn't be there. This is what I want:

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arrays_1 = [
    np.array(["row1", "row1", "row2", "row2"]),
    np.array(["type1", "type2", "type1", "type2"])
]

arrays_2 = [
    np.array(["col1", "col1", "col2", "col2"]),
    np.array(["load1", "load2", "load1", "load2"])
]

s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4), index=arrays_1, columns=arrays_2)
s.to_excel("test.xlsx")
```

I've also tried setting the names of index and column to None and I still get this issue. Not sure why this occurs.